# How to client-side timeout with an async generator function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, try-catch, generator, es6-promise

I want to force the catch statement to handle the error if the try block doesn't resolve within a certain amount of time. Below is the code that I'm trying to implement.

```
function* fn () {
  try {
    // if the following line doesn't resolve within 2ms
    // how can I throw an error that the catch block below will handle?
    // This line would be making a call to an API.
    // Regardless of the server's expiration, I want to simulate
    // a timeout after n seconds, cancel the request & exit the function.
    const res = yield call(...);
    const { data } = yield res;
  }
  catch(error) {
    yield put({...error});
    return error;
  }
}
```

I initially tried decorating the `const res = yield call(...)` statement in a decorator function that creates a `new Promise` and declares a timeout that `rejects` the response if not resolved, but I guess the control-flow for generators isn't the same as with promises as it did nothing.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: a candidate for `Promise.race` perhaps

Comment: So, `call()` returns a promise that you would like to timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You said async generator, but in the sample code you provided is using regular generator. So i am bit confused.

Below sample code is based on async generator

```
function promisedTimer(duration) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('Some random ID/string identifier'), duration);
    })
}

async function* fn () {
    try {
      const result = await Promise.race([promisedTimer(2), call(...)])
      if(result === "Some random ID/string identifier") {
            //Clean
            throw Error('Timeout');
      } else {
        const res = yield result;
        const { data } = yield res;
      }
    }
    catch(error) {
      yield put({...error});
      return error;
    }
}
```